# Define a templete class only using bool and char

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, restrict

I intended to have a class that only specifically dealing with bool or char type without using boost. My code is as below and I am using VS2017 Community:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
    typename std::enable_if_t< 
    std::is_same<T, bool>::value || std::is_same<T, char>::value >::type >
class BoolAndCharData
{
public:
    BoolAndCharData(const T& _data) {...}

    void DoSomething() {...}
}; // end of class BoolAndCharData


int main()
{
char c;
BoolAndCharData<char> data(c); //  error C2976: too few template parameter
....
} // end of main()
```

I tried the other way as someone presented in this site, compiler said it couldn't recognize the template:

```
template<typename T>
class BoolAndCharData<T, 
    typename std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T, bool>::value || 
    std::is_same<T, char>::value >::type >
{
public:
    BoolAndCharData(const T& _data) {...}

    void DoSomething() {...}
}; // end of class BoolAndCharData
```

I have browsed through this site and other webs for a few hours and found although there are quite some discussions over restricting template type, most either using boots or specific for a function. I still can't get it clear how to write a template class with selected data type. Can someone kindly point the way to rescue me from blindly trying ?

Comment: For a start, I would rename it to `BoolOrCharData`.

Comment: Thx for @TonyK's recommendation of naming and suggestion. The problem I presented indeed was from a larger set but I cut it out just to simplify the question. However, regardless whether there is a common base-class somewhere at some point the problem would still have to be  dealt with. Thx once again for your attention.

Comment: To whoever downvoted two of the answers: Downvotes for wrong answers, or for answers that doesn't really answer the question, those are okay and expected. But don't downvote just because you don't like a specific solution. If the answer actually *answers* the question then it doesn't deserve a downvote, much less so if it actually works. If you don't like the specific solution then please leave a comment saying what you think is wrong with it, or at the very least just leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `std::enable_if_t` to do that. A `static_assert` is enough in this case.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class BoolAndCharData {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, bool>::value or std::is_same<T, char>::value, "!");

public:
    BoolAndCharData(const T& _data) {}

    void DoSomething() {}
};

int main() {
    char c;
    BoolAndCharData<char> d1(c);
    // the following line won't compile
    // BoolAndCharData<int> d2(0);
    // ...
}
```

See it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9ee02aab678b318). Errors when using `static_assert` are also nicer than what you get out usually from templates.

Comment: I don't think that `or` should be there, should it?

Comment: @TonyK Yeah, why not? OP said char **or** bool, so `or` is appropriate. Note that `or` and `||` are both valid in C++. I like to use the first one with templates, I find them easier to read. Follow the link to Coliru to see it at work.

Comment: 35 years a programmer, and I learned something today! I wasn't aware of those alternative operators.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the following

```
template <typename, typename = void>
class BoolAndCharData;

template <typename T>
class BoolAndCharData<T, std::enable_if_t< 
   std::is_same<T, bool>::value || std::is_same<T, char>::value > >
 {
   public:
      BoolAndCharData(const T& _data)
       {}

      void DoSomething()
       {}
 };
```

A little variation on the theme is define a specific type-traits

```
template <typename, typename = void>
struct boolOrChar
 { };

template <typename T>
struct boolOrChar<bool, T>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct boolOrChar<char, T>
 { using type = T; };
```

so `BoolAndCharData` can be written as

```
template <typename, typename = void>
class BoolAndCharData;

template <typename T>
class BoolAndCharData<T, typename boolOrChar<T>::type>
 {
   public:
      BoolAndCharData(const T& _data)
       {}

      void DoSomething()
       {}
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template specialization, together with inheritance for the common code:

```
// Declares the generic case
template<typename T>
struct BoolAndCharData;

// Common base-class for the common code
template<typename T>
struct BoolAndCharDataCommon
{
    explicit BoolAndCharDataCommon(T) {}

    void DoSomething() {}
};

// Specialization for the char data-type
template<>
struct BoolAndCharData<char> : public BoolAndCharDataCommon<char>
{
    // To use the constructor(s) from the base class
    using BoolAndCharDataCommon::BoolAndCharDataCommon;
};

// Specialization for the bool data-type
template<>
struct BoolAndCharData<bool> : public BoolAndCharDataCommon<bool>
{
    // To use the constructor(s) from the base class
    using BoolAndCharDataCommon::BoolAndCharDataCommon;
};

int main()
{
    BoolAndCharData<char> a('a');
    BoolAndCharData<bool> b(false);

    a.DoSomething();
    b.DoSomething();

    // This will lead to a compiler error
    BoolAndCharData<int> c;
}
```

This way makes it easy to collect all common code, but also very easy to add code that is specific for the specific types if that's needed.